# DM-Script: Extract TagGroups of variable/unknown structure

Tags: null, tags, dm-script

My task seemed to be really easy: Use the `TagGroup` and extract the tree structure and the data **of an unknown** structure into the result log. So I want to get the name and the value and all the names and values of the children to be displayed in the results. How do I do this?

---

I have the following (example) Tag structure:

[image: Example tag structure]

The documentation writes about the `TagGroup` and also contains one example using `TagGroupGetTagType()`. The returned value can then be used to find the structure. I wrote and executed the following script:

```
for(number i = 0; i < tg.TagGroupCountTags(); i++){
    String label = tg.TagGroupGetTagLabel(i);
    number type = tg.TagGroupGetTagType(i, 0);

    result("\nName: " + label + ", Type: " + type);
}
```

Which gives

```
Name: Acquisition, Type: 3 // <- should be 0?
Name: Calibration, Type: 3
Name: DataBar, Type: 3 // <- should be 0?
Name: GMS Version, Type: 3 // <- should be 0?
Name: Microscope Info, Type: 3 // <- should be 0?
Name: Session Info, Type: 3 // <- should be 0?
```

According to the documentation a `TagGroup` has the type 0. This is not correct for my example. As the image shows *Acquisition* has children so it should have the type 0 but it has type 3. The same for (most of) the other indices. Type 3 is a long.

<sup>(In fact I wrote my own dummy `TagGroup`. I filled it with data types I know and then I tested the return value `TagGroupGetTagType()`. For this it seems that the documentation is correct.)</sup>

I changed my script to always force to check if the tag group has children assuming that `TagGroupCountTags()` would return 0 for empty tags but it doesn't:

```
void showTags(tg){
    for(number i = 0; i < tg.TagGroupCountTags(); i++){
        String label = tg.TagGroupGetTagLabel(i);
        number type = tg.TagGroupGetTagType(i, 0);

        result("\nName: " + label + ", Type: " + type);

        TagGroup child_tg;
        tg.TagGroupGetIndexedTagAsTagGroup(i, child_tg);

        // if(child_tg != NULL){ // <- this does not work either
        showTags(child_tg);
        // }
    }
}
```

This script crashes because `child_tg` is `null` at some time. But also I can't test for `null` because the comparism is not allowed (*Error "Unable to match this argument list to any existing function"*).

The documentation always knows its Tag structure, so they just use the path to get their values. Also I tried to find any other possibility on how to get if the `TagGroup` has children. But it seems there is no `hasChildren()` or any equivalent function. So how do I get the structure of the `TagGroup`?

<sup>Edit: Example data can be found at this [follow-up question post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61387398/1302888)</sup>

Comment: This is indeed odd. Which GMS version are you using, and what is the source of the TagGroup in your example? I've just tested GMS 3.4.0 with a STEM image (having similar tags), and can verify that TagGroups are of type 0.

Comment: I am also using GMS 3.4. I didn't create the source so I don't know the source. It was given to me as an example image.

Comment: See answers in your other [related question post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61387398/1302888). Your workaround solution is valid, but you can use the return value of the `GetTagAs...` commands directly for checks. The return value is Boolean and indicates success/failure of the operation.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but are you aware that the F1 help documentation example section has a script which exactly does what you try to do? It's **example #4** in the section *Scripting > Example Scripts > Tags, TagGroups and TagLists*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing for "NULL" of any script object is done with the "IsValid()" method. This may seem odd (how can NULL have a method?) but it's how it works.

So you have:

- `image img` --> `img.ImageIsValid()`
- `imageDocument doc` --> `doc.ImageDocumentIsValid()`
- `ROI r` --> `r.ROIIsValid()`
- `TagGroup tg` --> `tg.TagGroupIsValid()`
- etc. etc.
- also: `object ob` --> `ob.ScriptObjectIsValid()`

---

But a simpler solution for your problem is to use:

```
TagGroup child_tg;
if ( tg.TagGroupGetIndexedTagAsTagGroup(i, child_tg) )
    showTags(child_tg);
```

The `Get...` commands return a Boolean indicating success or failure of the operation.

Answer (score 0):

So I found some kind of an answer. I am now using

```
try{
    showTags(child_tg);
}
catch{
    break;
}
```

This works but still I am not very happy with this. Is there a way to compare to `null` or check the objects class (is there some kind of `instanceof`)?