# TagGroupGetTagType returns wrong type

Tags: dm-script

Basically this is the specific question for [my older question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60866079/5934316) which I just can't solve.

I was given an example image for my development. This image contains a (I guess representative) `TagGrop` that displays the information about how the image is created.

My problem is, that `TagGroupGetTagType()` of the elements of this `TagGroup` returns `3` for elements that are `TagGroups` itself. But `TagGroups` have the type `0` (confirmed by myself and @BmyGuest in the linked question). The following image shows the output of my example script together with the tag editor dialog. As one can see that every element has the type 3, including `TagGroups` like *Acquision* or others.

[image: Comparism of output and Tag Editor results]

The image above has been created with the following script:

```c
clearResults();

image img;
img.GetFrontImage();
TagGroup tg = img.ImageGetTagGroup();

TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow(tg, 0);

for(number i = 0; i < tg.TagGroupCountTags(); i++){
    String label = tg.TagGroupGetTagLabel(i);
    number type = tg.TagGroupGetTagType(i, 0);

    result("Index " + label + " has type " + type + "\n");
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does this not work? Is there any way to get the correct type?

This may be related to the file so I created an example file which is missing some of the indices (for protecting the privacy of the people who gave me this file). The posted output is in fact created with this file. So the same problem occurres. This file can be downloaded from https://www.file-upload.net/download-14020685/example.dm4.html.

<sub>(For anyone who doesn't like to download files from random pages you can get the base64 encoded file contents here: https://cutpaste.online/notes.html?id=xcix7x9e9sHxMFwF3e5h)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***A confirmation & Workaround***

Using your script and provided file, I can exactly reproduce the result.

Moreover, if I run the following script (in GMS 3.4):

```
image img := RealImage("Test",4,10,10)
taggroup newTG = NewTagGroup()
newTG.TagGroupSetTagAsString("Test","oh")
img.imagegettaggroup().TagGroupSetTagAsTagGroup("TG",newTG)
img.ShowImage()
```

And then run your script, I get:

```
Index GMS Version has type 0
Index TG has type 0
```

However, if I *save* the file and then open it up again and run your script, I suddenly get:

```
Index GMS Version has type 3
Index TG has type 3
```

So, something has clearly changed and is off. I tried some older data (all saved with GMS 3.x) and I always get a type 3 for TagGroups. I could not find data saved by GMS 2.x or GMS 1.x but would assume either or both would return type 0.

I've also noticed that the command `TagGroupGetTagTypeLength` returns 0 before saving, but 1 for the loaded image, and I think that might be related.

But there is a workaround you can use, which might solver your actual question.
For TagGroups (and TagLists) you can replace your check for the type by an actual attempt to get the tag as a TagGroup, as in:

```
clearResults();

image img;
img.GetFrontImage();
TagGroup tg = img.ImageGetTagGroup();

TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow(tg, 0);

for(number i = 0; i < tg.TagGroupCountTags(); i++){
    String label = tg.TagGroupGetTagLabel(i);
    number typeL = tg.TagGroupGetTagTypeLength(i);
    number type = tg.TagGroupGetTagType(i, 0);

    result("Index " + label + " has " + typeL + " types. Type = " + type + "\n");
    TagGroup tgtest
    if ( tg.TagGroupGetIndexedTagAsTagGroup(i,tgtest) )
        Result("\tIt is as TagGroup (or TagList)!\n")
}
```

Comment: I didn't think that it is related to saving. That is a very interesting turning point. Thank you for taking that much time for my problem. I will go with your workaround :)